# How to add fraction of a month to a date in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am designing a calculator for predicted completion dates. These depend on an input on months which are often in fractions of months - e.g. 48 months or 53.3 months etc. I want to add the months onto a start date but `EDATE` is ignoring the fraction and only adding the integer months. I want this to be exact and depend on leap years etc. I am aware that I could use a date function and use X*30 but this would be an estimate and could be days out since months have different numbers of days. Moreover, the input date will be continually changing for different things and some might require 2 dependent completion dates - e.g., in 12 months X, and in 25 months X2 and so on.

Not sure if this makes total sense but would be grateful for any advice. E.g., can I convert into days and back again using an origin date - that is what I would probably do in R.

See above but I used

> =EDATE(ORIGIN DATE, + NUMBER OF MONTHS)

Output was only using full integer of months.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this way:

```
=EDATE(A3,B3)+MOD(B3,1)*(EDATE(A3,B3+1)-EDATE(A3,B3))
```

[image: EDate]

The result contains fraction of a day which can be removed by rounding.

Comment: You've updated your answer?  Checked it before I added mine and 0.5 time was giving an incorrect value.  Is working now though so worth an upvote. :)

Comment: If OP is concerned with the fraction of the day, then return the time too. ;)

Comment: It is the idea only. If a month has 31 days, then 0.5 months can be counted as 15 or 16. These are details that OP did not write about.

Comment: This seems to work thank you. I don't know how EDATE is coded but presumably it does not necessarily take into account leap years etc. Ideally I would counting precisely from an origin date so it took into account the changing days in months - I have done this in R where you have an origin and can simply add days and the result will be the true date (i.e., if you were to literally count the days on your calendar).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?
The original date is in cell A3, the returned date is on row 4.

[image]

```
=LET(
    StartDate, $A$3,
    EndPoint, B2,
    EndMonth, EDATE(StartDate, EndPoint),
    MonthFraction, EndPoint - INT(EndPoint),
    DaysToAdd, INT(DAY(EOMONTH(EndMonth, 0)) * MonthFraction),
    Result, SUM(EndMonth, DaysToAdd),
    Result
)
```